# Android paint within an image

Tags: android, android-canvas

I need to paint a color in the white space inside the alphabet A using canvas. How can I do this?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Paint color while drawing the polygons. Example:

```
    Paint red = new Paint();
    red.setColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
    red.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
    path.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);
    path.moveTo(point2.x, point2.y);
    path.lineTo(point3.x, point3.y);
    path.moveTo(point3.x, point3.y);
    path.lineTo(point1.x, point1.y);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, red);
```